# how to obtain proper alignment of tables on top of each other with horizontal scrollbar at bottom

Tags: html, css

I want to know how to obtain proper alignment of tables on top of each other with horizontal scrollbar at bottom.

The demo HTML code is:

```
<div class="cntnr">
<div class="tabonecntnr">
    <table class="wd100 tabone">
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td>TABLENAME</td>
                <td>lorem ipsum</td>
                <td>ABC</td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>
<div class="tabtwocntnr">
    <table class="wd100 tabtwo">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Header 1</th>
            <th>Header 2</th>
            <th>Header 3</th>
            <th>Header 4</th>
            <th>Header 5</th>
            <th>Header 6</th>
            <th>Header 7</th>
            <th>Header 8</th>
            <th>Header 9</th>
            <th>Header 10</th>
            <th>Header 11</th>
            <th>Header 12</th>
            <th>Header 13</th>
            <th>Header 14</th>
            <th>Header 15</th>
            <th>Header 16</th>
            <th>Header 17</th>
            <th>Header 18</th>
            <th>Header 19</th>
            <th>Header 20</th>
            <th>Header 1</th>
            <th>Header 2</th>
            <th>Header 3</th>
            <th>Header 4</th>
            <th>Header 5</th>
            <th>Header 6</th>
            <th>Header 7</th>
            <th>Header 8</th>
            <th>Header 9</th>
            <th>Header 10</th>
            <th>Header 11</th>
            <th>Header 12</th>
            <th>Header 13</th>
            <th>Header 14</th>
            <th>Header 15</th>
            <th>Header 16</th>
            <th>Header 17</th>
            <th>Header 18</th>
            <th>Header 19</th>
            <th>Header 20</th>

        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
    </table>
</div>

</div>
```

The corresponding css is:

```
.wd100{
    width:100%;
}

.cntnr{
    overflow-x:auto;
    width: 100%;
    border: 1px solid black;
}
.bgred{
    background: red;
}
.tabone,.tabtwo{
    border-collapse: collapse;

}
.tabone td{
    background: red;
}
.tabonecntnr,.tabtwocntnr{
    width:100%;
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

As we can see the second table is not displayed completely.

I have tried applying `position:absolute;` and `table-layout:fixed;` properties to the inner divs and tables respectively but still could not get the correct result.

I want to know where I am going wrong.

Please contribute...

Comment: Actually, "we" can't see anything.. ;) Fiddle?

Comment: 'As we can see the second table is not displayed completely' - Possibly because there are 40 cells horizontally and they don't fit on your screen? [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/oGeez/cmxL7/)

Comment: jsfiddle.net/LA9wE/6 In this fiddle the white space is appearing on the right hand side of top table. How to remove it??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[**demo of exactly what you want**](http://jsfiddle.net/WMYve/3/)

**To do :** As chadocat suggested remove `overflow: hidden;` from `.tabonecntnr`

**Then**, to cover the top-table to full width as below table, do :

```
.wd100 {
    min-width:1000%; /* hack to give full width*/
    overflow:hidden; /*hide when the content is over */
}
```

**why need hack???** because...table or div would take up only `100%` of the width....you need to cover, even the `overflow` which is extended-width....greater that 100% width!!!

Comment: yours is not a full proof solution you can try resizing the output window

Comment: see...what you are trying to achieve is not a good layout in the first place....you could have easily achieved what you want to, using `display:table` properties....and if you explain what is *a full proof solution* according to you, i might be able to help!! :)

Comment: if you are worried about scroller in horizontal body, just add `overflow:hidden;` to it ( *not recommended though*)!! :)

Answer (score 2):

remove `overflow:hidden;` on `.tabonecntnr,.tabtwocntnr`

see this **[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/LA9wE/4/)**

Comment: doing so we get the white space on the right hand side of top table. How to remove the white space??

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/LA9wE/6/ In this fiddle the white space is appearing on the right hand side of top table. How to remove it

Comment: @user2594152 are the number of columns in `.tabtwo` fixed? if so the you can use `colspan`. for moire info, see here :http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_td_colspan.asp

Comment: can you show it by using the fiddle jsfiddle.net/LA9wE/6 please

Comment: if the columns in the second table are not fixed then is it possible to achieve what i want??

Comment: @user2594152 NoobEditor posted a solution for that just under

Answer (score 0):

the following change is to be made to your css

```
.tabonecntnr,.tabtwocntnr{
    width:100%;//overflow hidden removed.
}
```

Comment: jsfiddle.net/LA9wE/6 In this fiddle the white space is appearing on the right hand side of top table. How to remove it

Comment: Well what would you like to finally achieve!!the table name,lorem ispum shud be the headings of the table!?? if so you can use a single table in which the headings have colspan.

Comment: can you show it by using the fiddle jsfiddle.net/LA9wE/6 please

Comment: i want the last column which consists of ABC to be placed at the right most. Only there are three columns in the table header as we can see.
You can add dynamic columns between second and third column as you wish.